# Ascii error in test of zfec utility

Tags: python, terminal, runtime-error

I am trying to play with [zfec](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zfec), a fast erasure codec which can be used as a command line utility. The error I get is:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2022' in position 697: ordinal not in range(128)

Any ideas on how to remedy this? As a reference, here is the full textual output from the test:

```
$ python ./setup.py test
running test
Searching for argparse>=0.8
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/argparse/
Best match: argparse 1.2.1
Downloading http://argparse.googlecode.com/files/argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz#md5=2fbef8cb61e506c706957ab6e135840c
Processing argparse-1.2.1.tar.gz
Running argparse-1.2.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/dd/z2b28q_n0j5fb8qmxhrn80200000gn/T/easy_install-5I4rNB/argparse-1.2.1/egg-dist-tmp-0yDZUv
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.orig' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.rej' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...

Installed /Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/argparse-1.2.1-py2.5.egg
Searching for pyutil>=1.3.19
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyutil/
Best match: pyutil 1.9.7
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyutil/pyutil-1.9.7.tar.gz#md5=5a20ccae479d967d3fa11b905d0e10f6
Processing pyutil-1.9.7.tar.gz
Running pyutil-1.9.7/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/dd/z2b28q_n0j5fb8qmxhrn80200000gn/T/easy_install-oG8lMI/pyutil-1.9.7/egg-dist-tmp-2t_5qj
running test
Searching for pyutil>=1.3.19
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyutil/
Best match: pyutil 1.9.7
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyutil/pyutil-1.9.7.tar.gz#md5=5a20ccae479d967d3fa11b905d0e10f6
Processing pyutil-1.9.7.tar.gz
Running pyutil-1.9.7/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/dd/z2b28q_n0j5fb8qmxhrn80200000gn/T/easy_install-owyC0b/pyutil-1.9.7/egg-dist-tmp-IZuxzi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 191, in <module>
    _setup(repr(readmetext))
  File "./setup.py", line 185, in _setup
    zip_safe=False, # I prefer unzipped for easier access.
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/dist.py", line 1006, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/command/test.py", line 111, in run
    self.distribution.fetch_build_eggs(self.distribution.install_requires)
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 284, in fetch_build_eggs
    parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 573, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 823, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 835, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 327, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 453, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 483, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 663, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 938, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 927, in run_setup
    run_setup(setup_script, args)
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 62, in run_setup
    lambda: execfile(
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 105, in run
    return func()
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 64, in <lambda>
    {'__file__':setup_script, '__name__':'__main__'}
  File "setup.py", line 117, in <module>
    # before building sdists or eggs:
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/dist.py", line 1006, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/command/bdist_egg.py", line 167, in run
    self.run_command("egg_info")
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/cmd.py", line 333, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/dist.py", line 1006, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 170, in run
    writer(self, ep.name, os.path.join(self.egg_info,ep.name))
  File "/Users/Andrew/Documents/Academic Work/Computing/Extracurricular Programming/zfec-1.4.24/setuptools-0.6c16dev3.egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 379, in write_pkg_info
    metadata.write_pkg_info(cmd.egg_info)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/dist.py", line 1088, in write_pkg_info
    self.write_pkg_file(pkg_info)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/distutils/dist.py", line 1113, in write_pkg_file
    file.write('Description: %s\n' % long_desc)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2022' in position 697: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: This is a problem with the `pyutil` module using non-ASCII text `setup.py`, actually.

Comment: I suspect that it's the `setuptools` release that is not handling that correctly, I can install `pyutil` just fine with `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [`pyutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyutil), it worked for me.

This guys solved a similar problem installing `pyutil` in this [link](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.tahoe.devel/7927).